# List all methods and their return types from .class file in given path in java

Tags: java, file, class, methods, reflection

I was trying to read all methods and their return types from already complied .class files from the external path to see the structure of the file. If the compiled file is in your System or can be imported (eg String.class) then it's easy we can simply call this method and get the result. But is there a way to solve this problem for an externally compiled .class file? EDIT: with latest comment I used URLClassLoader but it is giving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyClassFile (wrong name: a/b/MyClassFile)

```
public class JavaMethodsNameGeneration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL classUrl;
        File file  = new File ("C:/Users/myPath");
        classUrl = file.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] classUrls = { classUrl };
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);
        Class myClass = ucl.loadClass("MyClassFile");
        System.out.println(generateMethodNameToFile(String.class));//Write the output string to file

    }
    public static String generateMethodNameToFile(Class className){

        Method[] methods = className.getMethods();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Arrays.stream(methods).forEach(method -> {
            stringBuilder.append(method.getName()).append("(");
            Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
            if(parameterTypes.length>0){
                Arrays.stream(parameterTypes).forEach(p->{
                    stringBuilder.append(p.getSimpleName()).append(",");
                });
            }
            else{
                stringBuilder.append(" ");
            }
            stringBuilder.setLength(Math.max(stringBuilder.length()-1,0));
            stringBuilder.append(")").append(" : ").append(method.getReturnType().equals(Void.class)?"void": method.getReturnType().getSimpleName());
            if(method.getExceptionTypes().length>0){
                stringBuilder.append(" throws ").append(Arrays.stream(method.getExceptionTypes()).map(Class::getSimpleName).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
            }
            stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        });
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please feel free to suggest proper tags for this question or edit this question for typos. Thanks

Comment: Create an `URLClassLoader` to load the class.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I tried your solution but I'm facing another issue here: ` URL classUrl;
        File file  = new File ("C:/Users/");
        classUrl = file.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] classUrls = { classUrl };
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);
        Class myClass = ucl.loadClass("MyClassFile"); ` but I'm getting this NoClassDefFoundError: (wrong name: com/a/b/c/d/e/f/MyClassFile)

Comment: @alwaysabeginner This is already another question. "Note, just copy-paste the code for me" questions are unwelcomed here.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Appreciate your reply but I don't think another question addresses the problem to read the methods from .class file which was compiled externally and placed in that directory. Part of the logic which is similar is to fetch methods which in any case would be iterating on the Methods[] and similarly on return type and exception. Also, the idea to use URLClassLoader was suggested and used from reference. Please note I also refered other answers to solve NoClassDefFoundError but there was no luck. I'm new to Java any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To be honest - you should consider using a different approach. a) there is javap b) use an `org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader`.